# How newtons law tells us there is no absolute rest

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

We know newton law tells us that there is no absolute rest as was previously thought. But how?
When we throw a ball up on earth it comes back obeying the law but when we throw the same ball in a moving train again it comes down. But it does not come to the same point on earth where it was thrown. It covers a distance as covered by the train. So here earth is not the absolute rest I think. Here the rest is the moving train I think. Am I thinking it right?
Thanks for help.

Comment: "Rest" is what ever frame you are in. Rest is frame dependant. Therefore there is no such thing as absolute rest. Since rest for someone else, might not be at rest for someone else. If I'm in a car, the steering wheel to me, is at rest. Yet for someone not In the car, the steering wheel is in motion

Comment: Galileo and Newton understood that velocity is relative. However (IIRC), Newton believed in an absolute rest frame for the universe, and absolute time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gallilean relativity:**
$$x' = x - vt$$

x is the coordinate in our original frame

x' is the coordinate of x in our new frame, where the new frame is moving with a constant velocity v with respect to the origin frame

**Moving objects:**

When an object in our original frame is moving with a CONSTANT velocity, the x coordinate of that object is a function of time

$$x'(t)=x(t)-vt$$

we would like to find the frame such that   in this new frame  the object has a velocity of 0, aka $\frac{dx'}{dt} = 0$

Differentiating

$$\frac{dx'}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} - v$$

$$0 = \frac{dx}{dt} - v$$

$$v = \frac{dx}{dt}$$

So this means that given I have a frame transformation such that I move with a velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}$  with respect to our original frame, The object will appear stationary. yet this same object is moving with a velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the  previous frame.

Meaning an object in one frame that is stationary, can have an apparent velocity in another frame.

Therefore, there is no such thing as absolute rest, since "rest" is frame dependant.

**Common sense:**

If I speed up to an object such that I match this objects speed, relative to my new frame, the object is stationary.

Comment: So we have a original frame at rest and a moving body with velocity v. Now there is no force on it so a=0 and the body is cruizing. But with gallilan transformation we can find a new frame where the v=0. So its not clear from newtons law is the body is at rest or moving with constant speed v. Right?

Comment: Newtons laws don't inherently prove absolute motion is invalid

Comment: Ok. So it’s not clear from newtons law and the use of gallilean relativity what is rest.

Comment: My English vocabulary is not so good. So you mean “alone” by “inherently”?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same, kind of

Comment: Unless you also have the fact newtons laws are the same in every inertial frame, from there you can determine the frame transformation necessary,  and then use the above reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I think I read recently that Newton believed that one could specify the speed of an object “through space”.   It was Einstein's special relativity that postulated that only the velocity relative to another object could be measured.